# How do I optimize this code that counts of inversions to sort an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, optimization, inversion

I'm trying to answer this test from Geeks for Geeks to count the number of inversions some array need to be sorted. I know my code works but they need me to optimize my code in order to post it. The **register** keyword was something I implemented, but it still doesn't work... Could you guys help me, please?

```
// Your Code Here
register int i, j, cont = 0;

for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    j = i + 1;
    while(j < N) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[j] && i < j) {
            cont++;
        }
        j++;
    }
}

return cont;
```

Comment: To do this properly you'll want to split this out into a *comparator* and a *sorter* that uses some arbitrary comparator.

Comment: Use of `register` here is really unwarranted. Let the compiler figure out if that's necessary. Use `-O3` and don't fuss over coaching.

Comment: `i < j` is always true as `j = i + 1` and `j` only increments subsequently, so you can remove this check, also use preincrement.